# WordPress async-upload.php 403 error after a while

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, http-status-code-403

I got a 403 error on async-upload.php uploading a file in media library.

*WordPress: Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page*

I have to logoff login again and start to work again. After a while (maybe 30 minutes) the same small jpg image, gave again this error.

This happened only with multi-file uploader. The browser uploader works fine in any case.

Some informations that could help you to help me:

1. Can't find any clue on wordpress/nginx/varnish/php log files
2. Tested without Cloudflare
3. Testes in diagnostic mode (no plugin, standard theme)

I'm going crazy. Please help me to find where or what to check.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the right permissions to Wordpress folder?

All folders should have 775 permission
All files should have 644 permission

see https://www.farukgaric.com/tech/wordpress-file-permissions/

I suppose it could be something related to cookies/session or HTTP connection in general.

In my case the 403 error pops out when I try to upload an image from front-end via /wp-admin/async-upload.php

This happen on Worpdress with WP ROCKET, DOKAN and Cloudflare, I'm figuring out how to fix it.